# Python function that creates max number from list of numbers

Tags: python

I want to make a function that creates max number from list of numbers.
list_of_numbers =[15, 56, 2]
I need in result 56215, but result is 15562.
How to make it work?

```
class Comporator():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        result_1 = str(self.number) + str(other.number)
        result_2 = str(other.number) + str(self.number)
        return int(result_1) < int(result_2)


def max_number(list_of_numbers):
    sorted(list_of_numbers, key = Comporator, reverse = True)
    return list_of_numbers 

def print_number(list_of_numbers):
    for i in list_of_numbers:
        print(i, end='')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_numbers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    max_number(list_of_numbers)
    print_number(list_of_numbers)
```

Comment: `sorted` returns a *new* sorted list. You're just returning your original, unsorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign **sorted(list_of_numbers, key = Comporator, reverse = True)** to a **variable**

Make following changes in the code

```
class Comporator():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        result_1 = str(self.number) + str(other.number)
        result_2 = str(other.number) + str(self.number)
        return int(result_1) < int(result_2)


def max_number(list_of_numbers):
    list_of_numbers = sorted(list_of_numbers, key = Comporator, reverse = True)
    return list_of_numbers 

def print_number(list_of_numbers):
    for i in list_of_numbers:
        print(i, end='')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_numbers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    list_of_numbers = max_number(list_of_numbers)
    print_number(list_of_numbers)
```

Comment: Or - just for fun - put it all together: `def max_number(list_of_numbers): return int(''.join(map(str, sorted(list_of_numbers, key=lambda s: str(s), reverse=True))))`